# Filtering Lists / Conditions on Lists with Python in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I'm new to python and after a lot of time trying to solve a problem, I'm pretty lost so I thought I'd ask my first question here.

I have a main file with a referenced file in Maya, where I am trying to list the connections of a certain node, for which the source is in the referenced file and the destination is in the main file

```
import pymel.core

# get relevant list:
aSourceNodeCC = cmds.ls ("ShaderReference:CC*")

# source details
for eSourceNodeCC in aSourceNodeCC:
    
    # destination details
    if cmds.connectionInfo ('%s.outColor' % eSourceNodeCC, destinationFromSource = 1) is not None:  
        aConnectionCC = cmds.connectionInfo ('%s.outColor' % eSourceNodeCC, destinationFromSource = 1)

        # list generation
        for eConnectionCC in aConnectionCC:
            aConnectionCCMaster = eSourceNodeCC + ('.outColor ') + eConnectionCC
            print aConnectionCCMaster
```

The issues I'm having is that the CC* nodes sometimes have connections within the referenced file as well as the main file. I only need the connections to the main file, and am struggling to filter out the ones that are connected to other nodes within the referenced file. i.e. I need to keep entries that look like:

*ShaderReference:CC_white.outColor SS_white_custom.baseColor*

but need to exclude entries that look like:

*ShaderReference:CC_white.outcolor ShaderReference:SS_white_custom.baseColor*

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
# list generation
    for eConnectionCC in aConnectionCC:

        # check if ref
        if cmds.referenceQuery(eConnectionCC, isNodeReferenced=True):
            continue

        aConnectionCCMaster = eSourceNodeCC + ('.outColor ') + eConnectionCC
        print aConnectionCCMaster
```